# Can't search for exact phrase

Tags: bug, search

When searching for `"model mommy"` there are 0 results.  I think the search should have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19554959/674039) result, at least.

I was able to find some posts by the same search without quotes, but also had to sort through some irrelevant results just because they contained one of the words.

Comment: Whole words, where period is considered part of a word. Searching for ["model mommy."](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22model+mommy.%22) works fine.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that "model mommy." worked, but I do consider that a bug.  I shouldn't have to search for "model mummy," etc. the search should be smart enough to split that punctuation off

Comment: As those words are in [a url this also works.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Amodel+mommy)